# you do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

i try to copy folder 'eclipse' into /usr using the command 'sudo cp -r /eclipse /usr/'

and then i click on folder 'eclipse' but it said 'you do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of eclipse'

it is on ubuntu and i know it is about the permissions but i do not know how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

You use sudo to copy folder, so folder need root permission to access.You need change owner for your folder

```
sudo chown -R [username login]:[username login] /usr/eclipse
```